# My Blender has no Header

Tags: python, interface, installation

When I opened Blender after installing them, I felt that something was wrong.
then I realized that the awkwardness came from how "empty" it was(See the picture below).
Does anyone know how to fix it and/or why it happend?

[image] As you can see, my Blender has no window, whats so ever.

Comment: This kind of thing can happen when there are issues with python, but the weird thing is that it looks like the outliner is unaffected..

Comment: The Outliner is entirely written in "C", that's why it is unaffected when something is broken with Python.

Comment: Did the Ui show up before? Best way is just reinstall it or use a zip(portable version).[▼Download](http://www.blender.org/download)

Comment: @Leon95 I reinstalled it and yes! it worked! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

While I have no immediate answer, here is how you can find out the cause of the problem:

1. Open a command line shell.
2. Navigate to where your Blender is installed.
   On windows you can <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> in the blender program folder (without any file selected) in Windows Explorer and select `Open command window here`.
   On linux this step is only necessary if you have multiple version of blender installed, otherwise you can just run `blender`.
3. Call blender from the shell. On windows, type `blender.exe`. On linux, type  `./blender`.

Now Blender starts and leaves messages in the commandline shell. You will probably see one or more error messages which may lead you to the cause of the problem.

You can try to force Blender to use factory-settings by providing the commandline option as follows:

```
blender.exe --factory-startup
```

Some possible causes are:

- a broken Addon
- An installation error like: "out of disk space", "no write permissions on disk", etc.
- Wrong Python version in Path (i am not sure if Blender gets trapped by that)

Comment: Even though I didn't get an error message, when I reinstalled it, it worked! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the window is either maximized or blender is running in fullscreen mode.

Did you try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + down-arrow or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>?

Comment: Burril  In a maximized window you wouldn't see the timeline on the bottom nor the properties or outliner windows on the right.